# ERROR: Permission to reagdan/author_template.git denied to blazinIce. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, permission-denied

I am fairly new to tech and recently hit a block with github.
So i used to use another github account(blazingIce) on my mac. I recently switched to another(reagdan) but i keep getting this error "ERROR: Permission to reagdan/author_template.git denied to blazinIce." fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
I checked my global name an email and they all check out. I unistalled and reinstalled git all over again.
I already checked the .git file too.
I don't know why it thinks i am trying to push from my old account.

Comment: Your name and email address are not used for authentication (since they're arbitrary strings that you can set to whatever you like). Instead, when you connect to GitHub, GitHub (not Git) authenticates you using either ssh or https. The details depend on which of these protocols you use to *reach* GitHub over the net. If you use https, GitHub demand a "user name" string such as `blazinIce` or `reagdan` and then a "token" (basically a glorified password). Git will provide this to GitHub using a *credential helper*, which you configure and which depends on your OS.

Comment: If you're using ssh instead of https, GitHub figures out who you are claiming to be by looking at the *public key* you hand them. Your computer does this through the `ssh` program, which is *completely* independent of Git (vs the credential helpers, which are *partly* independent). So if you're using ssh protocol, check your ssh configuration. See the GitHub help pages; they are extensive and cover both https and ssh, for WIndows, Linux, and macOS.

Comment: @torek. Thanks a lot. I already had an ssh key generated. but i generated another one and it added it to my github again. solved my problem. Really grateful for pushing me in the right direction